# Is there a way to install WebView2 Runtime from a msix store app

Tags: uwp, msix, webview2

I'm working on a hybrid pwa/uwp app which has a lot of issues on the old WebView but works perfect on WebView2, the thing is that I need to be sure that the Runtime is installed so my app can work and really don't like the idea of asking the user that install it himself.
I'm aware that WinUI3 is not supported yet so I'm trying to package the same logic on a wpf desktop app while I wait for WinUI3.

Trying to install the runtime programmatically ask for elevation permission which I understand are not allowed on the store, what I thinking to do is to add the installer on the MSIX but that's what I don't see how to do.

Comment: Hello, have you had any success with this?